# Flask function in link onClick doesn't work after going back with browser

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am using python flask framework to create a web project. In one of its pages, there is a link to another page which is like this:

```
<a onclick="{{ recipe.increment_clickcount() }}" href="/recipe/{{ recipe.id }}">{{ recipe.name }}</a>
```

Here I send `recipe` object to that page and it has a method called `increment_clickcount` which increments the clickcount variable in that recipe object by one. I do this to store how many times that recipe is clicked.

When I click that link it does what I want, Then I go back to the page where the link is in using the back button of the browser (Google Chrome). Then I click that link again but this time, it doesn't increment it. I refreshed the page then clicked that link and increment works fine again.

I assume it stored in the cache or something but I do not have enough iinformation about it.

How can I make this function work even when the above situation happened?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty function to the top of the JS (or HTML, for that matter) file of that page:

```
window.onunload = function(){};
```

But I'm now entirely sure that's what you need. If it was clicked already, isn't it more logical the click count will not increment ?